# Woher kommt "Schicht" in der Bedeutung "Ende"?

Tags: meaning, usage, colloquial

Diese Frage ist mir während eines Konzertmitschnitts von Jan Delay in den Sinn gekommen. Im Lied *St. Pauli* kommen folgende Zeilen vor:

> Auf St. Pauli brennt noch Licht.
>   Da ist noch lange noch nicht **Schicht**.

Ich finde diese Verwendung des Wortes **Schicht** bemerkenswert, denn eigentlich beschreibt das Wort einen gesamten Arbeitsabschnitt. Die Schicht geht also von Schichtbeginn bis Schichtende. Im Liedtext oben und in Aussprüchen wie *jetzt ist aber mal Schicht*, etc. wird das Wort **Schicht** aber im Sinne von **Schichtende** verwendet.

Ich frage mich: Wie ist es zu dieser Bedeutungsverschiebung gekommen?

Comment: Auch bekannt: *Schicht im Schacht*. Aber da sitzen wir bestimmt einem Henne-und-Ei-Problem auf, denn welche Schicht war denn nun zuerst? ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nach [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS07365#XGS07365) gibt es noch im Mittelhochdeutschen eine heute verloren gegangene Bedeutung von **Schicht**, synonym mit Geschichte:

> **Schicht**, f. , [...] Ableitung von ahd. *scehan* sich schicken, fügen, ereignen, das ebenfalls einfach nicht vorhanden, aber in **Geschehen** erhalten ist. In der Bedeutung ist *Schicht* synonym mit **Geschichte** [...].

Allerdings beschreiben die Grimms weiter unten, dass ein etymologischer Zusammenhang mit **Schicht** in der Bedeutung einer bestimmten Arbeitszeit nicht unumstritten ist:

> die Ansicht, dass das Wort eins mit dem vorigen subst. **Schicht** sei, und zu dem Verbum ahd. *scehan* sich schicken, fügen, ereignen gehöre, ist nicht unbezweifelt geblieben; man hat die Behauptung aufgestellt, dass Schicht in den folgenden Bedeutungen für **Schift** stehe, [...] engl. *shift*, tägliche Leistung, Tageswerk, Veränderung [...]; indes zeigt das alte Verbreitungsgebiet des deutschen Wortes, dass eine solche Annahme ganz unwahrscheinlich ist.

Doch habe **Schicht** seit mindestens dem 18. Jahrhundert auch die Bedeutung des Endes einer Arbeitszeit:

> **b)** das ende der Arbeitszeit und Arbeit bezeichnend, dann auch die Ruhezeit selbst, Feierabend; [...]
>   **α)** *in der Bergmannssprache:* ist die Schicht beendet, so sagt man, sie sei verfahren, und durch die Grube ertönt der Ruf: **'Schicht ist's!'**

Zusammenfassend lässt sich also feststellen, dass man vor allem im Bergbau, aber auch daneben, unter **Schicht** nicht nur eine feste Arbeitszeit, sondern auch das Ende dieser Arbeitszeit verstand.

Ein Zusammenhang mit dem mittelhochdeutschen **Schicht** in der Bedeutung von **Geschichte** liegt nahe, auch wenn die Grimms erwähnen, dass dieser Zusammenhang umstritten ist.